# Passing data through Subscribe method between two components

Tags: angular

I tried to pass my data via Subject using services but i do not see anything in the console for the first time i click on the edit button but then when i click on button for the second time i see the result
when i emit the values in admin products.component.ts

```
this.prservice.editproduct.next(this.editedproduct)
```

its working fine here, the issue is while subscribing i think and that too for the very first time i am clicking

admin-products.component.html

```
<button type="button" [routerLink]="['new']" mdbBtn color="primary" 
mdbWavesEffect>New Product</button>
< table mdbTable>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let head of headElements" scope="col">{{head}} </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let item of listofproducts;let id=index"
  >
  <th>{{id}}</th>
    <th scope="row">{{item.title}}</th>
    <td>{{item.price}}</td>

    <td  (click)="onclickedit(id)" class="edititem">Edit</td>

  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

admin-products.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Productservice } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
selector: 'app-admin-products',
templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.scss']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
listofproducts
editedproduct
constructor(private prservice:Productservice,private 
router:Router,private route:ActivatedRoute) { 

}

ngOnInit() {
this.listofproducts=this.prservice.getallproducts()


}


headElements = ['Title', 'Price'];
onclickedit(id){

this.editedproduct=this.prservice.getspecificproduct(id)

this.prservice.editproduct.next(this.editedproduct)
this.router.navigate(['edit',id],{relativeTo:this.route})
}

}
```

So i tried to pass editedproducts to another component here

Products.service.ts

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

export class Productservice{

productcard=new Subject<any>()

editproduct=new Subject<any>()
cards:any[]=[]


addtocardarray(value){
this.cards.push(value)
// console.log(this.cards)
}

getallproducts(){
    return this.cards
}
getspecificproduct(id){
    return this.cards[id]
}

}
```

edit-products.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Productservice } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
selector: 'app-edit-products',
templateUrl: './edit-products.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./edit-products.component.scss']
})
export class EditProductsComponent implements OnInit {
id:number
editproductdetails
subscription:Subscription
constructor(private prservice:Productservice,private 
router:Router,private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
// console.log(this.id)
this.route.params.subscribe(
  (params)=>{
    this.id=+params['id']
    console.log(this.id)
  }
)
this.subscription=this.prservice.editproduct.subscribe(
  (values)=>{
    console.log(values)
    this.editproductdetails=values
    console.log(this.editproductdetails)
  }
)

}

}
```

so here when i try to console log values or this.editproductsdetals i do not see anything in the console

Comment: Two things, first a quick question re: `Products.service.ts` shouldn't that have @Injectable() in there? 
Second, could you strip out anything unrelated to the issue and demonstrate it in a https://stackblitz.com/ ? it is much easier to see whats going on with a working app that can be investigated and debugged.

Answer (score 0):

Then the problem is that you pass a new value to the subject before the child component is created. And because of that child component is unaware of "subject" change, because it didn't happen after the subscription.

Normal `Subject` works like this. You have to subscribe to subject before it emits new value else it won't give you any value!

You should use `BehaviorSubject`. The difference here is that `BehaviorSubject` always holds a value. And when someone subscribes to it. It will emit the last value it held.